# MySQL many to many table to table matrix

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, matrix

I have a many to many table in MySQL - it can look something like:

```
A | B
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
3 | 4
3 | 5
4 | 1
4 | 2
4 | 5
```

etc.

You'll notice that the numbers are not always contiguous, (A=1,3,4..) - I am looking for the fastest way to turning this into a matrix table, ignoring columns and rows with no data (e.g. A=2). What I have working is painfully slow as I am taking each row into a separate array in php, going through a nested while loop, where it checks if the key for array A and array B match the current index:

```
while ($i <= $max_A) {
    if (in_array($i, $array_A)) {
        print ("<tr>");

        while ($j <= $max_B) {
            if (in_array($j, $array_B)) {
                print ("<td>");
                if (in_matrix($i, $j, $array_A, $array_B)) {
                    print ("1");
                } else {
                    print ("0");
                }
                print ("</td>");
            }
            $j++;
        }
        print ("</tr>\n");
        $j = $min_B;
    }
    $i++;
}

function in_matrix($search_value_A, $search_value_B, $array_A, $array_B) {
    // Store the array keys matching search
    $keys_A = array_keys($array_A, $search_value_A);
    $keys_B = array_keys($array_B, $search_value_B);
    foreach ($keys_A as $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $keys_B)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Perhaps there is more I can do MySQL side or speed up the search function - I tried finding a way to searching a two-dimensional array (e.g. return true if Column A = x AND Column B = y in a given row).

Thanks

Comment: What are `$i` and `$j` before your `while` loops commence?

Answer (score 3):

It's called pivoting the data when it's done in SQL, because you're changing row into columnar data:

```
   SELECT t.a,
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.b = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END),
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.b = 2 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END),
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.b = 3 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END),
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.b = 4 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END),
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.b = 5 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END),
     FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.a
```

The CASE statement is similar in structure to a SWITCH statement, but doesn't support fall through.  You'll have to define a CASE statement for each row value you want to output as a column.